# Powershell - How to get the GUID from a security group to assign acl

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I might be missing something, but I am trying to get the GUID from a security group to assign some delegated permissions.

I have a basic code see below;

```
$guidmap = get-adgroup -Filter "name -like 'MyOU'" -Properties *  | select objectguid

Write-host "Here is what you need: " $guidmap
```

Not sure why I can't seem to resolve the GUID on this.

Comment: Does `Get-AdUser` return anything? If not, perhaps change your filter to `"name -like '*MyOU*'"`

Comment: Don't ask for **all** properties if you only need the one. I guess you want `Select-Object -ExpandProperty objectGuid`

Comment: thanks for all suggestions, but still no luck, just nothing is out putting - I can see the attribute in ad though, so i'm at a loss as to why this wouldn't resolve - do security groups use GET-aduser or Get-ADGroup?

Comment: Security Groups are groups, and retrieved using `Get-ADGroup` or `Get-ADObject`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember is that Powershell is very much an object-based language. One of your best debugging tools will be the [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet. In this case, it turns out that the output from `Select-Object` is still an object of type ADGroup (specifically, `Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup`), when what you want is apparently either a `System.GUID` or a `System.String`.

If you want a `System.GUID`, try

```
$GUIDMap = (Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'MyOU'" -Properties ObjectGUID).ObjectGUID
```

or if you want a `System.String`, use

```
$GUIDMap = (Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'MyOU'" -Properties ObjectGUID).ObjectGUID.GUID
```

(*Incidentally, if you're retrieving the information for a single specific group, you don't need to use the `-Filter` parameter and expression; you can use `-Identity` instead - `Get-ADGroup -Identity MyOU -Properties ObjectGUID`...*)